# Is it possible to listen data changes on specified colums in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, stack-overflow

I'm doing a JTable with a kind of excel-like formulas, since some cells are automatically calculated.

I'm using TableModelListener to listen to data changes, and calling a function there to loop through all the data and calculate the value to each row, like this.

I'm calculating the column number 3 "uds", it contains an integer given by the colum pieces. For example if pieces has a value of "3" uds should be "1", or if pieces has a value of "3-5" uds should be "2"

```
private void maths() {
        //    0        1       2     3      4
        // Descrip - Pieces - PVP - Uds - Total - Done
        //                          Col 4 is Nº of "-"  (col2 * col3)
        int colDescrip = 0; int colPieces = 1; int colPvp = 2;  int colUds = 3; int colTotal = 4; //Columnas

        for(int row = 0; row < getTable().getRowCount(); row++) {

            String pieces = getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, colPiezas).toString();

            if(pieces != "") {
                Integer n = nOfHyphens(getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, colPieces).toString());
                System.out.println(n);
                getTable().getModel().setValueAt(n, row, colUds); //Error here
            }


            System.out.println("Col 0: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 0) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).getClass());
            System.out.println("Col 1: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 1) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).getClass());
            System.out.println("Col 2: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 2) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).getClass());
            System.out.println("Col 3: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 3) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 3).getClass());
            System.out.println("Col 4: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 4) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).getClass());
            System.out.println("#################");
        }

    }

    private int nOfHyphens(String s) {
        int t = 1;
        char c = '-';
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
            if(s.charAt(i) == c) 
                t++;

        return t;
    }
```

This `maths()` function is called inside `public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0)`, and my problem is that every time it calculates the total for each row, the data changes, and of course the event calls again and again until I get `StackOverflowError`, how can I prevent this? Making one JTable with data and another one with results? or is it possible to call this event only when a specified column changes?

Thanks.

**EDIT: Adding full code**

```
public class PresupuestoFrameNuevo extends JFrame{

    private JPanel tableHolder;
    private JPanel btnHolder;
    private JPanel btnleft;
    private JPanel btnright;

    private JScrollPane jsp;
    private JTable table;

    private JButton addrow;
    private JButton delrow;
    private JButton save;
    private JButton cancel;

    private ButtonListener BL;
    private TableListener TL;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new PresupuestoFrameNuevo();
    }

    public PresupuestoFrameNuevo() {
        setSize(1000,600);
        setTitle("Presupuesto nuevo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        initComps();
        drawComps();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComps() {

        setTable(new JTable(new PresupuestoModel()));
        setJsp(new JScrollPane(getTable()));

        getTable().getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        getTable().getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        getTable().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        getTable().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);   

        setTL(new TableListener());

        getTable().getModel().addTableModelListener(getTL());

        //Table width
        getTable().getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(300); //Descrip
        getTable().getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(80);//pvp unidad
        getTable().getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(70);//unidades
        getTable().getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(80);//total
        getTable().getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setMaxWidth(60);//hecho

        setTableHolder(new JPanel());
        setBtnHolder(new JPanel());
        setBtnleft(new JPanel());
        setBtnright(new JPanel());

        getTableHolder().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        getBtnHolder().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        setBL(new ButtonListener());

        setAddrow(new JButton("Add row"));
        setDelrow(new JButton("Delete row")); //TODO
        setSave(new JButton("Save"));         //TODO
        setCancel(new JButton("Cancel"));     //TODO

        getAddrow().addActionListener(getBL());
        getDelrow().addActionListener(getBL());
        getSave().addActionListener(getBL());
        getCancel().addActionListener(getBL());

    }

    private void drawComps() {

        getBtnleft().add(getAddrow());
        getBtnleft().add(getDelrow());
        getBtnright().add(getSave());
        getBtnright().add(getCancel());

        getBtnleft().setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Tools"));
        getBtnright().setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Options"));
        getTableHolder().add(getJsp());
        getBtnHolder().add(getBtnleft());
        getBtnHolder().add(getBtnright());

        add(getBtnHolder(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(getTableHolder(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(ae.getSource() == addrow) {
                ((PresupuestoModel) getTable().getModel()).addRow();
            }
            else if(ae.getSource() == delrow) {

            }
            else if(ae.getSource() == save) {

            }
            else if(ae.getSource() == cancel) {

            }

        }

    }

    private class TableListener implements TableModelListener{

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getSource());
            System.out.println(e.getSource().getClass());
            System.out.println(e.getColumn());

            /*if(e.getColumn() == 3) {
                return;
            }
            else {

                //maths();  
            }*/


        }

        private void maths() {
            //    0        1          2           3         4
            // Descrip - Piezas - PVP Unidad - Unidades - Total - Hecho
            //                                  Nº of "-"  2*3
            int colDescrip = 0; int colPieces = 1; int colPvp = 2;  int colUds = 3; int colTotal = 4; //Columnas

            for(int row = 0; row < getTable().getRowCount(); row++) {

                String pie = getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, colPieces).toString();

                if(pie != "") {
                    Integer n = nOfHyphens(getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, colPieces).toString());
                    System.out.println(n);
                    getTable().getModel().setValueAt(n, row, colUds);
                }


                System.out.println("Col 0: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 0) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).getClass());
                System.out.println("Col 1: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 1) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).getClass());
                System.out.println("Col 2: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 2) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).getClass());
                System.out.println("Col 3: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 3) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 3).getClass());
                System.out.println("Col 4: " + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 4) + "." + getTable().getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).getClass());
                System.out.println("#################");
            }

        }

        private int nOfHyphens(String s) {
            int t = 1;
            char c = '-';
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
                if(s.charAt(i) == c) 
                    t++;

            return t;
        }

    }

    public JPanel getTableHolder() {
        return tableHolder;
    }

    public void setTableHolder(JPanel tableHolder) {
        this.tableHolder = tableHolder;
    }

    public JPanel getBtnHolder() {
        return btnHolder;
    }

    public void setBtnHolder(JPanel btnHolder) {
        this.btnHolder = btnHolder;
    }

    public JPanel getBtnleft() {
        return btnleft;
    }

    public void setBtnleft(JPanel btnleft) {
        this.btnleft = btnleft;
    }

    public JPanel getBtnright() {
        return btnright;
    }

    public void setBtnright(JPanel btnright) {
        this.btnright = btnright;
    }

    public JScrollPane getJsp() {
        return jsp;
    }

    public void setJsp(JScrollPane jsp) {
        this.jsp = jsp;
    }

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public JButton getAddrow() {
        return addrow;
    }

    public void setAddrow(JButton addrow) {
        this.addrow = addrow;
    }

    public JButton getDelrow() {
        return delrow;
    }

    public void setDelrow(JButton delrow) {
        this.delrow = delrow;
    }

    public JButton getSave() {
        return save;
    }

    public void setSave(JButton save) {
        this.save = save;
    }

    public JButton getCancel() {
        return cancel;
    }

    public void setCancel(JButton cancel) {
        this.cancel = cancel;
    }

    public ButtonListener getBL() {
        return BL;
    }

    public void setBL(ButtonListener bL) {
        BL = bL;
    }

    public TableListener getTL() {
        return TL;
    }

    public void setTL(TableListener tL) {
        TL = tL;
    }



}
```

TableModel

```
public class PresupuestoModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] cols = { "Description", "Pieces", "PVP U", "Uds", "Total", "Done" };
    private Vector<Object[]> data;

    public PresupuestoModel() {
        setData(new Vector<Object[]>());
    }

    public void addRow() {
        Object[] s = new Object[getCols().length];

        for (int i = 0; i < getCols().length; i++) {
            if (i != getCols().length - 1)
                s[i] = "";
            else
                s[i] = new Boolean(false);
        }

        getData().add(s);
        fireTableRowsInserted(getRowCount() - 1, getColumnCount());
    }

    public void deleteRow(int index) {
        getData().remove(index);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(index, index);
    }

    public String getColumnName(int n) {
        return getCols()[n];
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if ((col == 3) || (col == 4)) 
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
        if (c == getCols().length - 1) {
            return Boolean.class;
        }
        else if((c == 2) || (c == 3)) {
            return Integer.class;
        }
        else { 
            return String.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return (getData().get(rowIndex))[columnIndex];
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        System.out.println("Object: " + value + "." + value.getClass()+ "[" + row + "," + col + "]");
        if(col == getCols().length - 1) {
            (getData().get(row))[col] = value;
        }
        else if((col > 1) || (col < 5))  {
            (getData().get(row))[col] = value;
        }
        else {
            (getData().get(row))[col] = value.toString();
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return getCols().length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return getData().size();
    }

    public String[] getCols() {
        return cols;
    }

    public void setCols(String[] cols) {
        this.cols = cols;
    }

    public Vector<Object[]> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Vector<Object[]> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TableModelEvent parameter has a `getColumn()` method that will tell you the column that is being changed and causing the event. You can use an if block, check the int returned by this method, and if the ignored column, simply call `return;`

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent event) {
    if (event.getColumn() == COLUMN_TO_IGNORE) {
        return;
    } else {
        maths();
    }
}
```

Comment: The event.getColumn() is returning -1 always, Why?

Comment: @Frankovich: consider creating and posting a [mcve] so we can run and test your code ourselves. Please read the link.

Comment: @Frankovich: per the [TableModelEvent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html), -1 corresponds to the `TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS` constant value. Now to figure out why....

Comment: Thank you!, I figured out why, i was calling at `setValueAt(Object o, int row, int col)` the `fireTableDataChanged()` and I changed it to `fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);` and now its returning the correct column at the TableModelEvent

Comment: @Frankovich: that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the update!